# Error 401 on Angular-NestJs page when refreshing token with Auth0

Tags: angular, jwt, nestjs, passport.js, auth0

I have created an application with Angular as Frontend and NestJs as Backend using Auth0 as authentication system.

In Angular I have put the authentication button and it works correctly. When the user authenticates, the request to /token is made correctly and this value is used to add it to the headers that will make the requests to the NestJS API. It works correctly, however, when a new request is made to /token (for example when refreshing the page), when sending the token through the headers, I receive a 401 error from NestJS.

I have to say that NestJS uses Passport JWT as authentication strategy.

I have not been able to determine why it does not work on subsequent requests (but it does on the first one). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding the issuer parameter in the Angular interceptor configuration that adds the token in the API request headers. That way the API can now correctly validate the refreshed tokens.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you get "401 Unauthorized" in case "Authorization" header forming and sending to the API server correctly.

But generally I believe you shouldn't request a new token such often (like every page reload) but only once the current token get expired or a little earlier.

So once you've got 401 error on any endpoint (probably except `GET /token` and so on in your setup) it's the right time to request a new token. In some scenarios it might be better to made it a bit sooner, based on something like `iat (issued at)` property encoded to the token. You can check what is inside yours here https://jwt.io.

Also in case of Angular most likely you'll implement token refresh logic inside an interceptor [like so](https://www.bezkoder.com/angular-12-refresh-token/#Angular_12_Refresh_Token_with_Interceptor).

Comment: Hi @Andrey Etumyan, In principle the fact that Angular through the Auth0 library sends a new request on each page refresh, as I have read is the normal behavior, ie, such a request is only made through the refresh (f5), not in the SPA navigation.

When a refresh occurs, the /token request returns a different token than the token received in the login process.

Comment: If I add the token received in the login in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/), it is decoded correctly: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLjN6.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQmIK.png

Comment: Now, if I decode the token received in the new request made to /token when refreshing the page using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/), it says that the token is not valid, so I guess NestJs does not accept it as valid and so it returns 401.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Erxdm.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GYOq.png